# Has Ethan Hunt ever refused a mission?

Tags: mission-impossible

In the Mission: Impossible series and movies, Ethan Hunt's mission briefings always end with the sentence "Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to (...)". Has he ever used that option and refused a mission?

Comment: Do you count occurrences in the corresponding TV-shows (don't know if it ever happened there, long time since I watched them). If yes, you may want to edit your question to make it less *Ethan Hunt* specific. I don't think it ever happened in the movies (haven't seen the last one though).

Comment: @ChristianRau he didn't refuse either.  And yes, I would make this more TV centric as there are only 4 movies in which he has accepted each mission.

Comment: @TylerShads That's what I thought. Taking only the movies into account makes a ridiculously trivial question. Othwerwise it would be quite interresting (even if not less trivial), as I always liked the shows, both the old one and the new one.

Comment: It would make for an awfully short movie.

Comment: It would be easy to invent a scenario in which he refuses, but gets involved anyway.

Comment: [**NO**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible_(film_series))

Comment: In the TV series there was no Ethan Hunt. The main character was Jim Phelps (played by the late Peter Graves) who was turned into the villain in the first movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure the asker is asking about the Mission Impossible film series because there was no character named Ethan Hunt in the the [TV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060009/fullcredits#cast). Ethan hunt was the name of the IMF operative in the [film series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission%3a_Impossible_%28film_series%29).

> The films feature Tom Cruise as Ethan Hunt, an IMF agent.

And in the film series, he never refused a mission, we know that.